# Can you answer a book in English?

Tags: word-request

In Spanish when it comes to answer the questions written in a book as well as filling in the blanks inside that same book we use the Spanish equivalent for the English verb answer. I mean you do answer the questions whether they are written or spoken but I am not sure if one could "answer a book". You do the exercises inside the book, you fill in the blanks using a pen or a pencil but, is there any special word or phrasal verb used to talk about filling-in  the blanks inside a book?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "answer a book" in English.

Alternatives are:

Complete a workbook, having (done/gone through) all the exercises.
Do the exercises.
Fill in (all) the blanks.
Answer (all) the questions.
Work through the questions and answer them.
etc.